# SYMFONY FORM - filter attribute form on top with submit button, that provides a table with other form used to edit each row details

Tags: forms, symfony

I am looking for best practices on SYMFONY FORM handling to achieve the following standard page (surprisingly I haven't found anything similar existing yet on SO).

Here is a shema of what I want to achieve:

[image][image]

As you can see at the top there is a SYMFONY FORM to filter the results that should be displayed.

It displays a table and each tuple of the table should permit to open another SYMFONY FORM kind linked to the tuple.

I am in the process of learning SYMFONY FORM, so far, I can manage to create the top row FORM to set the filter that'll apply to the table display.

But I wonder if anyone has experience on the second part: **Displaying the table that embed as well many forms of a similar kind** -That seems a bit more complex. I read about TWIG.EXTENSION and FORM.COLLECTION, I'll investigate that. But if someone could save me to re-invent the wheel and lead me to some direct shortcut, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if it's the best practice, but one way to do it would be to create a new property for your entity being listed in this table, called $editionForm (without mapping it to the database) for example.

Then, either throught a custom loop or by listening to a doctrine (or any ORM you use) hydration event (or triggering such an event if you don't use any ORM), fill the property with the generated form, probably within a dedicated service.

Then, just use it in your template like this :

```
$entity->getEditionForm()->render()
```

Comment: Thanks @VaN, I take your tip, listening to event seems to be a solution for the clickable edit button (more symfony reading to do (re-do) :P). I don't use ORM, I use PDO for DB query.